# How to reduce time taken by sas macro code to run

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need help with my monthly report sas code below:
Firstly the code takes too long to run while the data is relatively small. When it completes a message that reads:  The contents of log is too large.

Please can you check what the issue which my code?
Meaning of macro variable:
&end_date. = last day of the previous month. for instance 30-Apr-22
&lastest_refrsh_dt. = The latest date the report was published.
once the report is published, we updated the config table with &end_date.
work.schedule_dt: a table that contains the update flag. if all flags are true, we proceed but if update flags are false exit. at the six day of month, if the flag is still false, then email that reads "data not available" is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, that message about the log is due to warnings in the logs over type issues. From what you describe, it is typically due to an issue on date interpretation.

There is nothing in this post to aid in helping beyond that. You need to open the log and find out what the message is. Otherwise, it is speculation on our part.